# How does hash() compute the hash of a tuple?

Tags: python, hashcode

How does the function [`hash()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#hash) compute the hash value of a tuple? For example:

```
t = (1,2,3)
print(hash(t))
```

Gives an output

```
-378539185
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can check the [implementation of this function in C](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/22d25085db2590932b3664ca32ab82c08f2eb2db/Objects/tupleobject.c#L348) if you're familiar with C programming and some advanced math. It seems that algorithm XORs hashes of each element in tuple and adds some magic.

```c
static Py_hash_t
tuplehash(PyTupleObject *v)
{
    Py_uhash_t x;  /* Unsigned for defined overflow behavior. */
    Py_hash_t y;
    Py_ssize_t len = Py_SIZE(v);
    PyObject **p;
    Py_uhash_t mult = _PyHASH_MULTIPLIER;
    x = 0x345678UL;
    p = v->ob_item;
    while (--len >= 0) {
        y = PyObject_Hash(*p++);
        if (y == -1)
            return -1;
        x = (x ^ y) * mult;
        /* the cast might truncate len; that doesn't change hash stability */
        mult += (Py_hash_t)(82520UL + len + len);
    }
    x += 97531UL;
    if (x == (Py_uhash_t)-1)
        x = -2;
    return x;
}
```

Note that this is CPython's *current* implementation. Other Python interpreters and even other versions of CPython may have different hash functions. This particular implementation, called SipHash, has been in use since 2013. See [PEP 456 -- Secure and interchangeable hash algorithm](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0456/) for a detailed explanation.

> SipHash is a cryptographic pseudo random function with a 128-bit seed and 64-bit output.... SipHash is a family of pseudorandom functions (a.k.a. keyed hash functions) optimized for speed on short messages. Target applications include network traffic authentication and defense against hash-flooding DoS attacks.

Comment: the important part is that Python progressively takes the hash of each element of the tuple and combines that into a rolling hash value that becomes the final result.

Comment: also, the code above is not the core SipHash algorithm.

Comment: What is that. final overflow check useful for? What are the chances you land at exactly `(Py_uhash_t) -1` and why make it `-2` at that point?

Answer (score -1):

The [standard library documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#hash) has a little bit of detail.  Hash functions generally have the properties:

1. If two values are equal, they always have the same hash value; and
2. If two values are different, they probably have different hash values.

There are simpler and harder ways to write these, and faster and slower ways, but the important thing is how rarely different values produce the same hash value.  A good one is tricky, but you usually don't care deeply about the implementation.

(In Python you almost never need to directly call `hash()`; I wouldn't be surprised if it's part of the dictionary implementation for custom types used as keys.  The [`Object.__hash__()` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__hash__) says quite a bit more.)

Comment: The OP asked for specific detail about how the hash of a _tuple_ is calculated, not about hashes in general.