# Is hashing tuples an O(n) operation?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Let's say you do the following:

```
for row in myListofLists:
  if tuple(row) in myDictWithTupleKeys:
```

in other words, within a loop through the rows of an n x n array, you check to see if a row is contained as a key within a `dict`. Is this an O(n^2) operation? In other words, is the `in` operator an O(n) operation here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does python compute the hash of a tuple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49722196/how-does-python-compute-the-hash-of-a-tuple) or [How does hash() compute the hash of a tuple?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51593173/how-does-hash-compute-the-hash-of-a-tuple)

Comment: So a tuple's hash depends on the hash of its elements, and that can also be some large number deep @jtbandes, but presumably, in a simple tuple of integers, that makes it O(n) the tuple size, assuming the hash of ints is an O(1) operation?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: `tuple(row)` is already O(n) anyway.